# How to require flux Dispatcher in React Native

Tags: react-native

In React require Dispatcher using
`var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;`

How to require it in React Native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the same way in your Dispatcher

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;

module.exports = new Dispatcher();
```

In your Stores

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
```

(change the path accordingly)

Comment: Do you have flux module installed? checkout package.json